# What units are \pgfphysicalheight and \pgfphysicalwidth defined in?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths, pgfpages

I often use `\pgfphysicalheight` and `\pgfphysicalwidth` from the `pgfpages` package to define sizes dynamically based on the dimensions of my page (which vary). For example, here's a "dynamic" vertical space:

```
\vspace*{.04\pgfphysicalheight}
```

**What units are these pgf values actually in?** In other words, what is the value of `\pgfphysicalheight` if my document height is 10in?

I found nothing in the `pgfpages` docs. Also tried logging the values with `\show`, but got something cryptic like "\dimen195" which I couldn't decipher further.

Comment: use `\showthe` not `\show`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A TeX length (dimen or skip) register does not store the units used when the value is set, whether you use `pt` or `cm` or whatever is not recorded and it just saves the value as an integer which is the length in `sp`, if you look at the value using `\the` or `\showthe` then TeX will show the value using `pt` units (that is, the stored integer divided by 65536)

On the terminal you could see this for example by:

```
$ latex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

*\textheight=10in

*\showthe\textheight
> 722.7pt.
<*> \showthe\textheight
```